# driver list is considered as string in selenium webriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am passing a `list(driverList[])` of all the driver instances to another function which performs `driver.close()` to close all the open browser instances.

This list is considered as string even though it's a list of all the driver objects. So I am getting this error

> 'str has no attribute close'

Following is the simple code.

```
def function1(self):
     driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
     driver1.get(www.google.com)
     driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
     driver2.get(www.google.com) 
     driverList = [driver1,driver2]
     return driverList

def function2(self,driverList):
     driverList[0].close()
     driverList[1].close()
```

When I execute this second function, it gives me this error

> 'str has no attribute close'

. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you shared contains errors in function1. www.google.com should be passed as a string otherwise the get function arises an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the scope of your objects between the functions.

```
def function2(self,driverList):
    print driverList      
    driverList[0].close()
    driverList[1].close()

def function1(self, response):
    self.driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()

    self.driver1.get("http://www.google.com")
    self.driver2.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
    driverList = [self.driver1,self.driver2]
    self.function2(driverList)
```

The output of printing the driverList is:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver object at 0x111d4fc90>, 

<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver object at 0x111d5bd50>]
```

**UPDATE:** full code used to test and solve the issue (scrapy+selenium.webdriver)

```
class WindowSpider1(CrawlSpider):
    name = "windows"
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.com"]


    def function2(self,driverList):
        print driverList
        driverList[0].close()
        driverList[1].close()


    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()

        self.driver1.get("http://www.google.com")
        self.driver2.get("http://www.yahoo.com")
        driverList = [self.driver1,self.driver2]
        self.function2(driverList)
```

Comment: Yes, correct. This is the driverList. But when I pass it to the function2(), it considers it as a string. So, it can't close the drivers due to this. That's a problem.

Comment: the following code works for me and the windows are correctly closed. I am posting all the code used to test your issue. I used for simplicity scrapy+webdriver.